# Ayuda al bajar Imágenes Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, bitmap

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que requiere bajar 3 imágenes jpg de 2 mb casi cada jpg, estilo mercado libre (que baja y te muestra las fotos del producto) y cada vez que lo intento me genera un error, mi código intenta algo asi:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("------------");

    File imgFile = new  File("/prueba.jpg");
    storageRef.child("Articulos/"+mId+"/0.jpg").getFile(imgFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.e("Mylog","Se logro la transaccion");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("Mylog","Error: "+e);
        }
    });
```

Solía repetir 3 códigos para la descarga pero me genera crash en la aplicación. Hay alguna método, algo que este omitiendo que me pueda ayudar? el error que me genera es este:

> com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

Comment: ¿Podrías probar cambiando la linea `File imgFile = new  File("/prueba.jpg");` por `File imgFile = File.createTempFile("prueba", "jpg");` por si el archivo no existe? por otro lado prueba a obtener la referencia así `StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();`

Comment: Hola Jesus, esas imágenes son para mostrar únicamente o vas a estar modificando los archivos?